# Flash Builder Export Release Build Fails

Tags: eclipse, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm having an issue when trying to export the release build of my AIR application in Flash Builder 4.5.  After choosing the key to sign the package and clicking finish to complete the export, it errors saying that "Error occurred while saving the project settings: "default" build target cannot be found for the selected project."  I've included the error message output to the log in the .metadata folder.  Any help would be great as this is baffling to me.

```
!ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2011-05-10 15:56:11.432
!MESSAGE Failed to get build target settings: default
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.internal.FlexProjectCore.createErrorSta tus(FlexProjectCore.java:1009)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.util.logging.GlobalLogImpl.log(GlobalLogImpl.ja va:66)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.util.logging.GlobalLog.log(GlobalLog.java:52)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ProjectBuildPackagingUI.doAppl ySettings(ProjectBuildPackagingUI.java:754)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ProjectBuildPackagingUI.applyS ettings(ProjectBuildPackagingUI.java:781)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVer sionBuildPackagingPageContent.saveSettings(ExportReleaseVersionBuildPa ckagingPageContent.java:131)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVer sionBuildPackagingPage.saveSettings(ExportReleaseVersionBuildPackaging Page.java:84)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVer sionWizard.performFinish(ExportReleaseVersionWizard.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java :811)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java :430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java: 234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersio nAction$1.run(ExportReleaseVersionAction.java:97)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersio nAction.run(ExportReleaseVersionAction.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:2 51)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginActio n.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection (ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContri butionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionC ontributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.ja va:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.jav a:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication.start(FlashB uilderApplication.java:108)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandl e.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runAppli cation(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ec lipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja va:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja va:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

#### Update:

I have tried what J_A_X has recommended. Unfortunately none of those work. It seems to be a problem somewhere within the project settings. We have also tried running the export release build for this project on different machines with fresh installs of flash builder, but the same error message is produced every time. We've looked through so many settings it may come down to having to create a new project and copy all the code into the new application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although quite an old post I have just run into the same problem using Flash Builder 4.6.  I am fairly new to Air/Flex/Flash etc so apologies in advance for any terminology errors!  Still whilst trying to export my new project I did come across exactly the same error as you, and after a lot of searching on Google and starting to lose the will to live, tried Bing and found this link http://forums.adobe.com/thread/850398?start=0&tstart=0

When your Flash Builder project is closed edit the .actionScriptProperties file in Notepad and have a look for a buildTargets section - in my file this was simply `<buildTargets/>`.  I replaced it with the snippet Sandeep had posted in the forum

```
<buildTargets>
    <buildTarget buildTargetName="default">
      <airSettings airCertificatePath="" airTimestamp="true" anePathSet="false" version="1">
        <airExcludes/>
        <anePaths/>
      </airSettings>
      <actionScriptSettings version="1"/>
    </buildTarget>
  </buildTargets>
```

To my delight it was then possible to export my application as a release build.

By the sounds of things from other forums, for your settings file to be in this state in the first place may be due to older versions of FB or in my case I'm pretty sure it is because I used AIRLaunchPad to create my project - which did seem like a good idea at the time.  Anyway I hope this may help anyone in the same predicament!

Comment: Ran into the same problem, however, flash builder (4.6) gave me an error at startup and wouldn't build.  To get it to work for me, I modified the default build target above and added a "multiPlatformSettings" element between the airsettings and actionscriptsettings elements, as so:



<multiPlatformSettings enabled="false" includePlatformLibs="false" platformID="default" version="2"/>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it..

1. In Flash Builder, you have to right-click your project -> properties
2. Click "ActionScript Applications" in the left column
3. Click Add, and select your main document class, which would be specified in Flash
   Professional

Answer (score 0):

Look like an eclipse error.  Try to restart eclipse and see if that helps. Might be that Flash Builder was mis-installed (which normally means you see other error) or that your memory settings are too low, you should check your [eclipse.ini to increase memory](http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58).